# how work id^=value in javascript

Tags: jquery

```
        $("[id^='Qty-']").each(function() {

            itemElementId = $(this).attr('id');
            var productId = 0;
            productId = itemElementId.replace("Qty-", "");

            postArr[index] = { ProductId: productId, Qty: $(this).val() }
            index++;
        });
```

I can't understand  $("[id^='Qty-']") meaning. why use this. please help me

Comment: Its a selector which have id attribute value start from Qty-

Comment: Refer to [the CSS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) and [the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), both of which explain what that is. The documentation should be the **first** step in your research prior to asking a question.

Comment: But when increment Index where index++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some JQuery basics:

The selector $("[id^='Qty-']") will search for all the elements having attribute Id having value starting with Qty-

here's an example how this selector is looking for id values Qty- and displaying the content of td

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("[id^='Qty-']").each(function(){
alert($(this).html());
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
  <td id="Qty-1">Qty1</td>
  <td id=Qty-2>Qty2</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

For more information and learning, please refer this link on attribute selectors. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr Hussain patel and Rakesh Sajitra.

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.

Comment: Currently i have understood about the meaning of $("[id^='Qty-']")

itemElementId = $(this).attr('id');
            var productId = 0;
            productId = itemElementId.replace("Qty-", "");

            postArr[index] = { ProductId: productId, Qty: $(this).val() }
            index++

can't understand postArr[Index]={ ProductId: productId, Qty: $(this).val() }
            index++ 

why use index++

Comment: itemElementId = $(this).attr('id');  - is getting the value of id and storing in in itemElementId , then  in this productId = itemElementId.replace("Qty-", ""); from the value the Qty is replace and the id is extracted and stored in productId. then a json object is created and stored in postArr array and so the index is incremented..  hope this helps..

Comment: I couldn't understand clearly. if i want individually increment index from 0 using "each" statement its not working. But how this use for increment index please help me